# Why does dynamic method invoke fail when reflection still works?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, com

Why can't a `dynamic` object invoke these methods on the NameTranslate COM object when reflection can?

**Failing example using dynamic:**

```
Type ntt = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NameTranslate");
dynamic nto = Activator.CreateInstance(ntt);
nto.Init(3,null)
```

The third line fails with a NotImplementedException and the message *The method or operation is not implemented.*

**A similar attempt that works using a different COM object ([WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)):**

```
Type shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);
shell.SendKeys("abc");
```

Getting back to the first sample. If I use reflection and invoke the methods using the [InvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method things work fine.

**Working example using reflection:**

```
Type ntt = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NameTranslate");
object nto = Activator.CreateInstance(ntt);
object[] initParams = new object[]{3,null};
ntt.InvokeMember("Init", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, nto, initParams);
```

I believe this must have something to do with how the COM object is created or marked - but for the life of me I can't see anything in the docs, object browser or registry that indicates these COM objects and their subs/functions are marked private or something else that would normally throw off the `dynamic` keyword.

NameTranslate documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa706046.aspx

Comment: Try both of your techniques, only with second parameter not `null` - `nto.Init(3,<somethig>)`

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what the second parameter is - the NotImplementedException is the same. According to the docs the parameter is ignored anyway when the first parameter `lnInitType` is 3 (ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC).

Comment: Interestingly enough, none of `NameTranslate` methods are callable via `dynamic`.

Comment: I think, what happening is, when certain parameters entered, somewhere in `NameTranslate` some private method or even `case` is called and it is not implemented and exception is thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly, none of `NameTranslate` methods are callable via `dynamic`. I have only a theoretical explanation of this, below.

AFAIK, when .NET DLR deals with COM objects for `dynamic` invocation, it tries to make use of a COM type library, if available, and then resorts to `IDispatch`. That's how it is different from Reflection, which calls `IDispatch` right away when used with COM objects.

The ActiveDS type library (`C:\Windows\System32\activeds.tlb`), as viewed with OleView, appears to be somewhat ill-formed. It includes a lot of non-automation compatible declarations, including interfaces:

```
interface IPrivateDispatch;
interface ITypeInfo;
interface ITypeComp;
interface ITypeLib;
interface IPrivateUnknown;
```

The class definition for `NameTranslate` itself looks like this:

```
[
  uuid(274FAE1F-3626-11D1-A3A4-00C04FB950DC)
]
coclass NameTranslate {
    [default] interface IADsNameTranslate;
    interface IDispatch;
};
```

It's unusual (although not prohibited) to declare `IDispatch` inside `coclass`.

So, I'd assume such type library and/or `coclass` definition might be confusing the DLR in this case.

**As a workaround**, you can import it with `TlbImp.exe activeds.tlb` (that would produce a bunch of warnings), add the output interop assembly to your project and call the API directly. This works:

```
Type ntt = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NameTranslate");
var nto = Activator.CreateInstance(ntt) as ActiveDs.IADsNameTranslate;
nto.Init(3, null);
```